# in modal set theory, why it is issue?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory, axioms, philosophy, modal-logic

I have been studying the Iterative Set Concept within the context of the paper titled "Modal Set Theory" from Menzel specifically on pages 11-12.

*"As we’ve just seen, the iterative conception of set provides a cogent answer to that question: only those pluralities that “run out” by some level of the cumulative hierarchy constitute sets at the next level and, obviously, the entire hierarchy is not such a plurality; there is no level at which the members of all the levels form a set. Rather, the question is: Why is the hierarchy only as “high” as it is? Why do all the urelements and sets that there actually are fail to constitute a further level that kicks off yet another series of iterations?*

I understand that in this context, the question pertains to why a particular set is at its level within the hierarchy and why existing sets do not seem to initiate further iterations. I interpreted the former as being naturally determined by the definition of sets, so I'm unsure why this question poses an issue. As for the latter, I couldn't grasp its significance. Why is this question problematic within the framework of the Iterative Set Concept and the hierarchy of sets?

Comment: See [Von Neumann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_universe) for the hierarchy of sets. The "universe" is open ended, i.e. there is no last level in the hierarchy. See Ch.2 of Menzel's paper. But then, see Ch.3, a natural question arise: "Why is the hierarchy only as “high” as it is?" See D.2 page 9: if the operation of "collecting" all levels works at the limit ordinal stage, why a similar operation cannot be performed at "to constitute a further level that kicks off yet another series of iterations?"

Comment: Does the question "Why is the hierarchy only as 'high' as it is?" mean that the levels in the Von Neumann universe don't reveal the entire range of levels but are limited to the height up to which the current iteration is progressing? And I still don't understand the meaning of the question, "if the operation of 'collecting' all levels works at the limit ordinal stage, why a similar operation cannot be performed to constitute a further level that kicks off yet another series of iterations?"

Comment: What does it mean that a similar operation cannot be performed when it's already possible, according to the D2 definition, to move to the next stage by taking the union of the current stage and the power set of the current stage?

Comment: "Why is the hierarchy only as high as it is?", if we think of the Universe of Sets as a Tower segmented into levels, each ordinal α, represents some height. The entire hierarchy therefore, has "height" Ord, where Ord is the Proper Class containing every Ordinal. So, why is the height of the Universe the same as the height as the Ordinals? That's what the question is getting at.

Comment: The next question, about being unable to go to the next stage is about this idea: At the limit ordinal stage, we take the Union of all the previous levels to generate a new level. So, why can't we take the Union of every level in the entire heirarchy, to generate a new level as we did at the limit stages? Basically, why does taking Unions of levels stop producing sets? Note: The union of every level produces V = { x | x = x }, the Universe which is not a set.

Comment: Both of these questions, basically amount to: Why does the Union of every level, create the entire Universe of Sets? Why doesn't it just create another big set, which we can use to make even more sets? One answer, is that if it did, then the set of all Ordinals, would itself be a set. Which, leads to an immediate contradiction, as it is a Proper Class because if it were a set then it would be an Ordinal, and so it would be an element of itself- contradiction as ordinals are irreflexive w.r.t. elementhood